# Swift - Mutated property is reset before NSArchiving array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

This odd behavior as I feel the logic is legit.

Basically, I have an array of Player objects. I call a function to set the `isActive` property of each object to `true` and replace the object in the array. I then call `savePlayers` to archive my updated objects array to disk but the property I had set seems to reset back to `false`.

Swift 4

Xcode 9.2

iOS 11.0

Here's the relevant code:

```
var players = [Player]()

func activatePlayers() {
    for (index, player) in players.enumerated() {
         player.isActive = true
        players[index] = player
    }

    // just as a test, see if property is there/updated
    for(_, player) in players.enumerated() {
        print("\(player.name): \(player.isActive)") // prints “chris: true”
    }

    savePlayers()
}

func savePlayers()
{
    // just a test to see if property is mutated
    for(_, player) in players.enumerated() {
       print("\(player.name): \(player.isActive)") // prints “chris: false”
    }

    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(players, toFile: Player.archiveURL.path)
}
```

There isn't any other code that would be mutating the properties outside of what I posted. Is it a threading issue? Is there something different I should be doing?

Hoping I've just been staring at this too long and someone will point out the obvious!

Comment: Please post code that actually compiles. There are a lot of errors in your question's code.

Comment: There are still 6 errors in your question's code. Make it easy for people to help and post valid, testable code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line might cause the problem:

```
players.[index] = player
```

After you set the `isActive` property to `true`, you assign the object in which `isActive`is still set to `false` back to the array. This is due to the nature of for loops in Swift. You don't modify the original item in the array, but a **copy** of it.

Consider using this for loop (untested):

```
for index in 0..<players.count {
    players[index].isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Seems like you might be on the right path though I'm getting the same result. Even cloned the object and inserted at index. Stepping through breakpoints, the correct values are all there until I get to the `savePlayers` method - old values are back.

Setting up a playground with a really basic example, this works as expected. That tells me there's something else going on in my code that I need to investigate. Thanks for your suggestion.